# Changing heading at a certain point

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to change the heading of turtles in a traffic model.

```
  to setup-merging-cars
    set color blue
    setxy -14 -17
    set heading 45
    set speed 0.1 + random 9.9
    set speed-limit (((random 11) / 10) + 1)
    set max-patience ((random 50) + 10)
    set patience (max-patience - (random 10))
    loop [
       ifelse any? other turtles-here [ fd 1 ] [ stop ]

    ask turtles[
      if ycor > -2 [set heading 90]]
     ]
   end
```

I want it to change its heading from 45 to 90 at (0,-2) but when I run it, it stays on 45 and never changes.
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the **Traffic 2 Lanes** example model *from NetLogo 6** (not the earlier versions). You might find some inspiration there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, you are asking turtles to ask turtles. A nested version of things which will cause some issues.

Remove the ask turtles { before if ycor.

Comment: I have tried it with and without "ask turtles" and in both cases, it stays on the 45 heading

Comment: I added the "if" command later in the code and it worked. Thanks for the help!